# How to make KMail ask again for the program to open a specific filetype?

Tags: kmail

I opened a svg file that was attached to a mail and clicked to fast on the "don't ask me again" button when KMail asked me with which program the file should be opened.

The Konqueror settings only allow to select the order of the programs.

How can I restore the behavior?

Comment: Have you tried solving this yourself ?

Comment: Yes. I changed the file association in konqueror and systemsettings and the order for the associated program for a file type. But that didn't help.